# Taking picture, then putting the picture on an ImageView. Trying to make it full screen but I can't figure it out.

Tags: android

Title explains it pretty well. I successfully take a picture, then turn that byte array into a bmp, then put the bmp on an ImageView that *should* be full screen. But it's too small.

[image: The ImageView (which is supposed to be full screen) on top of the camera preview]

That picture is the ImageView (assigned a picture I just took) on top of the preview. Here's the relevant code.

```
Camera.PictureCallback jpgCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picPreview);
        image.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        image.setRotation(90);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
```

```
<SurfaceView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Take Picture"
    android:id="@+id/takePicButton"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#ff6cafff"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="takePic"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/picPreview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>
```

I've tried changing scaleType to center, centerCrop, default, and more, and nothing made the picture full screen.

Anyone have any idea what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! The problem was that I was rotating the ImageView, when I needed to rotate the image itself (bmp)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is your image isn't very high resolution. `ImageView` will do everything it can to position your content, but won't modify the content itself. In this case, the `picPreview` View is probably correctly filling the parent container, but the image is too small and is thus centered and not stretched.

So for example, your screen might be 1920x1080, while that picture is only 1280x720. ImageView won't stretch the image by default.

Try adding this to your activity code:

```
  ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picPreview)
  imgView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Comment: woops. Editted (have to cast the view as an imageView)

Comment: Now it fits horizontally, but the height is too low. This is odd. http://i.imgur.com/JIXPzmy.jpg